# How Can I load Inline CSS in the Redactor Editor?

Tags: craft3, redactor

In Redactor I put some content but I don’t know why Inline CSS is not load? Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first go to the Settings > Fields

Then click on the particular field in which you have selected the Redactor as a field type.

Then you can see Advanced option at the end of the page and Uncheck "Remove inline styles" options there.

[image]

So Redactor Editor will not remove inline CSS from your added html content.